Redirect linux process stdout to multiple incoming tcp connections
I have a worker process than produces its output onto the stdout pipe.
I would now want to have a service that echoes the stdout of this process to multiple incoming tcp peer connections.
In other words, I want to

redirect stdout of a process to a tcp "server" port of the local machine
... so that this tcp port can accept multiple incoming tcp connections
... and relay the stdout contents to all of these incoming connections

The stdin pipe can be ignored.
Question accordingly: Can I achieve this with some existing command line utility, or do I need to write a repeater tool myself e.g. with Python?

I tested using socat and that can serve part of the need, but not in full:

socat can redirect stdout to a tcp port and it can accept incoming connections from multiple peer hosts
however, socat doesn't echo the stdout stream data to all connections in full, but each connection receive partial stdout data in seemingly random way.

For reference, this is how I tested using socat:
An oneliner bash dummy example that serves updating round N echo entry to port 8080:
for i in {0..10000}; do echo "round ${i}"; sleep 1; done | socat - TCP-LISTEN:8080,fork,reuseaddr
If listening this example dummy stream with two nc localhost 8080 peer connections, both peers receive some of the stdout stream but neither receive all:
Connection 1 receives:
round 1
round 2
round 4
round 7
Connection 2 receives:
round 3
round 5
round 6
round 8
Expectation is that both connections would receive all the 'round 1, round 2, round 3 ...' etc entries.

Socat 1.8 distribution contains the script socat-mux.sh for use on Linux that should do what you need:
for i in {0..10000}; do echo "round ${i}"; sleep 1; done | socat-mux.sh TCP-LISTEN:8080 STDIN

Now connect with TCP clients, they should receive the data.
Please note that this script uses broadcasts on loopback, so any local users might read along.

Wonderful, this is exactly what was needed!
My linux server distro has socat version 1.7.4 which doesn't yet contain that socat-mux.sh script, yet the script file downloaded from the socat git repository turns out working fine with the socat 1.7 executable.

Sounds like you are looking for a pub-sub solution. There are many ways to achieve this, e.g.:
Redis
Producer(s):
for i in {0..10000}; do echo "round ${i}"; sleep 1; done |
while read s; do printf "publish topic '%s'\n" "$s" | redis-cli; done

Subscriber(s):
printf "subscribe topic\n" | redis-cli

MQTT
Producer(s):
for i in {0..10000}; do echo "round ${i}"; sleep 1; done |
mosquitto_pub -t topic -l

Subscriber(s):
mosquitto_sub -t topic

ZeroMQ
ZeroMQ can be configured in a myriad of ways, e.g. you can find an example implementation of the publish-subscribe pattern here.

Thank you for the suggestions. While using an intermediate message queue protocol is indeed a recommendable solution for many cases, in this particular the intention is to receive the stdout stream 1:1 in original format from TCP socket i.e. the application does not allow applying an intermediate wrapper protocol between the incoming data stream and the subscriber peer (apart from TCP socket).
